# How to make sure Windows PC is reasonably secure?

Tags: networking, security

I'm not much of a network and network security expert, but I need to add an existing Windows PC to a network with always on connection.

The problem is, I have no idea if the PC is really clean, and, actually, no knowledge to check it.

I scanned the PC with Process Explorer to verify if all running processes are signed, ran an AVG scan, but this is where my knowledge ends.

IIRC, there can be bad code attached to svchost or something, bad drivers, and so on, but I have no idea how to check all those things.

Reformatting the PC is unfeasible as of now. Are there any suggestions on what I could do?

Answer (score 5):

A golden rule: treat your network like your daughter. You wouldn't want a dodgy guy being plugged into her. Who knows what diseases can spread from there :)

In normal language: Don't trust it? Don't put it in the network.

Answer (score 2):

It'll probably take longer than its worth and require quite a bit work work but there's a few things I can think of. To start with it helps to actually know what kind of threat you're looking for, and no one tool is infallible

Firstly make sure *every single process running* is known. Yes, look through them all. Check all the services on the system - here's [microsoft's default list](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sys_srv_default_settings.mspx?mfr=true) and the [blackviper list](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-xp-x86-32-bit-service-pack-3-service-configurations/). Check for rootkits, with rootkit revealer and [gmer](http://www.gmer.net/), *then* do another check with an offline disk. Check processes with [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Run a few more malware scans to be sure (I tend to favour malwarebytes) including a few offline ones (microsoft system sweeper perhaps?).

That covers most situations, tho you still can't be sure.

Better yet, just work off a known good, trustworthy system to start with ;)